# How can I add the "nemometro TS231 [m/s]" data for each day?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am using mysql and I have a database in which I have to add the values of "TS231 anemometro [m / s]" for each day but when I write the code it does not work for me and I think it is because it takes the values of time and considers which are different dates. How can I make it add up the values per day?

[image]

I wrote the following command in MySQL

```
SELECT `fecha` ,sum(`Anemometro TS231 [m/s]`)FROM `data_candidatos_a` GROUP BY Fecha
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `extract` to get only year and month from date and group by year month:

```
select 
    extract(YEAR_MONTH From fecha)
    ,sum(`Anemometro TS231 [m/s]`)
FROM `data_candidatos_a` 
GROUP BY extract(YEAR_MONTH From fecha)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this for each day, extract the date:

```
SELECT DATE(fecha`), SUM(`Anemometro TS231 [m/s]`)
FROM `data_candidatos_a`
GROUP BY DATE(fecha);
```